# getting sum for each month for several months in a year in sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have the following table
[image of database in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K45VS.png)
i want to get the following kind of results

jan 12500
feb 16500
mar 4500
apr 6500

the query should return a total for each month for desired months.
i know how to do this..

```
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(cost) as january FROM earnings WHERE month= 1 and year= '$2022" ;
```

to get the sum for a given month but I cant find anything on how to get multiple months at once.
am still new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(cost) as cost,
   month 
FROM earnings 
WHERE year = :year  
GROUP BY month
```

Sum all entries of cost, per month (GROUP BY) found in year (:year)
Each ROW will have a column `cost` and `month`.

If you want to "further" filter the months you can apply another AND clause

`AND (month >= 1 OR month <= 6)` for January to June

Useful Source:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: unexpected ordering of clauses near (GROUP BY)??

Comment: my bad mariadb is mysql

Comment: While this surely answers your question, I strongly suggest you follow an SQL tutorial, such as https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

The thing you asked is a basic function of the SQL language.